# Spring AMQP (BatchingRabbitTemplate)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have question about BatchingRabbitTemplate ?

Fisrt, I use batch stategy to publish message. I wonder if message < batchSize for a long time spring amqp will be publish message automaticaly right? eg. timeout

Second, What is the best appropriate value of batchingRabbitTemplate(batchSize,bufferLimit, timeout)

Finally, What is the timeout parameter (BatchingRabbitTemplate)

Thank a lot ^^

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default `SimpleBatchingStrategy` will cause a "short" batch to be sent if the total size exceeds the buffer limit or the time since the last message exceeds the timeout.

```java
/**
 * @param batchSize the batch size.
 * @param bufferLimit the max buffer size; could trigger a short batch. Does not apply
 * to a single message.
 * @param timeout the batch timeout.
 */
public SimpleBatchingStrategy(int batchSize, int bufferLimit, long timeout) {
    this.batchSize = batchSize;
    this.bufferLimit = bufferLimit;
    this.timeout = timeout;
}
```

There is no "best" value for the timeout - that is entirely up to you to decide.